# How to set a cross hair icon in exact middle of the camera overlay?

Tags: ios

I would think MyImagePicker.frame.center is where I should place the icon (subtract icon.size.width/2 and height /2., but when the picture actually saves, what I thought the cross hair is pointing at is not the middle of the image at all. X seems okay, but Y happens to be some distance off. I can approximate by trial and error, but I would like to be exact.

Help?

Comment: icon.center = MyImagePicker.center;  // Make sure your icon does not have empty space on the sides.

Answer (score 1):

The `frame` actually defines the origin and dimensions of the view in the coordinate system of its **superview** and is commonly used during layout to adjust the size or position of the view as detailed [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame).

You most likely want to use `MyImagePicker.bounds.size.width / 2` and `MyImagePicker.bounds.size.height / 2` to get the actual center of your image picker.

I actually learned this recently by watching the Stanford lecture series on iOS 5 development on iTunes U.